# Comparing an two objects with arrays for quality

Tags: javascript, lodash, object-comparison

I am currently building a filter system and I am encountering a problem where I want to prevent double filtering if the order of array elements are changed.

For example, I got this object:

```js
const filters = {
  brands: [],
  models: [],
}
```

User A chooses the brand Audi (id `5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8a9`) and BMW (id `5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8aa`)
So you get this object:

```
{
  brands: ["5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8a9", "5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8aa"],
  models: [],
}
```

User B does the same, but in opposite (so first BMW, then Audi). So we end up with this:

```
{
  brands: ["5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8aa", "5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8a9"],
  models: [],
}
```

*(Notice the difference between the order of brands)*

Now when I check these for equality using `Lodash` [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) with this code:

```js
const _ = require("lodash");

const filtersA = {
    brands: ["5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8a9", "5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8aa"],
    models: [],
};

const filtersB = {
    brands: ["5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8aa", "5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8a9"],
    models: [],
};

console.log(_.isEqual(filtersA, filtersB));
```

This returns `false` unfortunately, then I tried comparing only the brands together, like:

```js
console.log(_.isEqual(filtersA.brands, filtersB.brands);
```

That also returns `false`.

**My goal is to return true if the filters in the object are equal, without looking at the order of the other filter. As long as the same items exist it should return true**

I also read something about `Lodash` [isEqualWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqualWith), but I am not really understanding how to use it.

Comment: `Array.sort()` your arrays before comparing them

Comment: There are many ways this can be (and have been) implemented. If performance will matter you'll need to investigate, but this is easily searchable on SO and the web.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can you link me something? I've tried but didn't find any working solutions..

Comment: P.s. Speed is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using the following function, this will only work if the two objects have the same structure.

```js
const _ = require("lodash");

const filtersA = {
    brands: ["5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8a9", "5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8aa"],
    models: [],
};

const filtersB = {
    brands: ["5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8aa", "5f1d5077b261aa63f42cc8a9"],
    models: [],
};

/**
 * Checks if two objects with arrays are equal
 *
 * @param {Object} a
 * @param {Object} b
 */
const areObjectWithArraysEqual = (a, b) => Object.keys(a).every((key) => _.isEqual(a[key].sort(), b[key].sort()));

console.log(areObjectWithArraysEqual(filtersA, filtersB));
```

This returns `true` as expected